# PC does not recognize phone anymore

Tags: usb, android, phone

Im using Ubuntu 16.04 on a PC.  Up until recently my PC recognized my phone (a rooted Oneplus One running CM13.0) when connected with a regular charging cable.  I tried rebooting the PC as well as the phone. When I plug the phone into the PC nothing happens even after the phone is unlocked and file transfer is selected on the phone.  I did try connecting the phone to a windows7 pc and everything worked as normal.  Any ideas?

Comment: What changed between when it was working and now? Did you change settings, install software, upgrade something?

Comment: I was trying to setup Samba and file sharing.  I had installed Garmin Samba, have been trying to get Garmin Samba to work...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about reading the files on the phone. On my phone at least, when I connect to the PC via USB, there is a little icon on the top bar of the android. Clicking to bring down the "menu" you should see an entry like charging via usb. You click on that and see several options. In my case I need to click "file transfer" and then I have access.

Comment: Correct. I do the same and it used to work that way but it no longer does.  I tried this on my windows machine and it worked without any issues

Comment: If you give me some more details, I can try it on my machine

Comment: What other info would you need?  Could it be the addition of the software Garmin Samba, I was trying to add the regular Samba for file sharing between Ubuntu PC's but couldn't get it to work...

Comment: I don't have Garmin Samba so I probably won't be able to help. Just for your info, there is something strange which I see. If I generate a csv file on the telephone, then I can see the file using the phone's file explorer, but I won't see the new file from the PC until I reboot the phone. This looks like some sort of bug inside Android.